# python. subprocess problem with windows task bar

Tags: python, taskbar, system-tray, trayicon, tray

I am trying to make an app in tray that would switch power plans if user was inactive for 5 minutes. The main problem is that it shows in task bar for every 5 sec (so, when the loop starts). But the problem happens only when I compile this to exe via pyinstaller, in Python compiler this works as it should.

[my problem (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtczU.gif)

pyinstaller command:
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astlofo4.ico" --name "Astlofo"  "C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/helper.py"`

**code of the problem function is:**

```
def inactive():
    while True:
        output = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-getactivescheme"])
        if (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) > 300000: #300000
            if not output == b'GUID \xe1\xe5\xa5\xac\xeb \xaf\xa8\xe2\xa0\xad\xa8\xef: 30edd295-bb03-4f04-9ca5-1d6625c371f5  (\x8f\xe0\xae\xe1\xe2\xae\xa9)':
                subprocess.call("powercfg /s 30edd295-bb03-4f04-9ca5-1d6625c371f5")
                print('power saving')
                systray.update(icon='C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astolfo2inactive.ico')
        else:
            if not output == b'GUID \xe1\xe5\xa5\xac\xeb \xaf\xa8\xe2\xa0\xad\xa8\xef: 04d7a134-5010-4cd2-ac8e-0bd74104d4fa  (\x8d\xa5 \xa8\xa3\xe0\xeb)':
                subprocess.call("powercfg /s 04d7a134-5010-4cd2-ac8e-0bd74104d4fa")
                print('balanced')
                systray.update(icon='C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astolfo2.ico')
        time.sleep(5)
```

**Full code of the programm:**

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
from PIL import ImageGrab
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
import psutil, time, keyboard, os, subprocess, win32api, threading
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

only_but = 1
text = 'Zoom'

def onquit(systray):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == "Астольфік.exe":
            proc.kill()

def open_dir(systray):
    os.startfile('C:/Users/LEGION/Pictures/Zoom')
def only_button(systray):
    global only_but, text
    if only_but == 0:
        only_but = 1  # only Zoom
        text = 'Zoom'
    elif only_but == 1:
        only_but = 2  # const on
        text = 'const on'
    elif only_but == 2:
        only_but = 0  # off
        text = 'off'

    systray.update(hover_text=f"Всього {len(os.listdir('C:/Users/LEGION/Pictures/Zoom/'))} screens| {text}")
    return only_but


# saving screenshot whether the Zoom is on or const on and mouse4 pressed
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):  # mouse4 is pressed
    global only_but, text
    if pressed and (button == mouse.Button.x1) and (only_but != 0):
        if ((button == mouse.Button.x1) and (("Zoom.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())
        and (only_but == 1))) or ((button == mouse.Button.x1) and (only_but == 2))):

            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
            keyboard.send('alt+SNAPSHOT')
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                try:
                    img.save(f'C:/Users/LEGION/Pictures/Zoom/{timestamp}.png')
                except:
                    print('ERROR saving')
            except:
                print('ERROR clipboard')

            systray.update(hover_text=f"Всього {len(os.listdir('C:/Users/LEGION/Pictures/Zoom/'))} скриншотів | {text}")


menu = (("Screens dir", 'C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/folder.ico', open_dir),
        ('Switch', None, only_button),
        )
systray = SysTrayIcon("C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astolfo2.ico",
                      f"{len(os.listdir('C:/Users/LEGION/Pictures/Zoom/'))} Screens| {text}", menu,
                      on_quit=onquit, default_menu_index=2)
systray.start()


def inactive():
    while True:
        output = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-getactivescheme"])
        if (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) > 300000: #300000
            if not output == b'GUID \xe1\xe5\xa5\xac\xeb \xaf\xa8\xe2\xa0\xad\xa8\xef: 30edd295-bb03-4f04-9ca5-1d6625c371f5  (\x8f\xe0\xae\xe1\xe2\xae\xa9)':
                subprocess.call("powercfg /s 30edd295-bb03-4f04-9ca5-1d6625c371f5")
                print('power saving')
                systray.update(icon='C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astolfo2dnd.ico')
        else:
            if not output == b'GUID \xe1\xe5\xa5\xac\xeb \xaf\xa8\xe2\xa0\xad\xa8\xef: 04d7a134-5010-4cd2-ac8e-0bd74104d4fa  (\x8d\xa5 \xa8\xa3\xe0\xeb)':
                subprocess.call("powercfg /s 04d7a134-5010-4cd2-ac8e-0bd74104d4fa")
                print('balanced')
                systray.update(icon='C:/Users/LEGION/PycharmProjects/game/astolfo2.ico')
        time.sleep(5)

# Collect events until released
def mouse_listener():
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=inactive)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=mouse_listener)
thread2.start()
```

Hope we can make this work

Comment: If the `systray.update` call is the cause, you could of course remember the last setting and only call it again when it changes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It's not. I removed all the `systray.update` and nothing changed. Could problem be in  `subprocess.check_output`?

Comment: You could try to play around with the Windows-specific arguments `creationflags` and `startupinfo` of `check_output` and `call`. Especially you can try `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` as value for `creationflags`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks! `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` worked for `check_output` and for `call` I've looked into creationflags and found `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW`